# Update README.md automatically

Tags: github

Can I somehow add line or update read me file automatically on every pull request? For example if i have read me file with version on every pull request i want to add new line on top with the new version 1.0.1 (example if previous was 1.0.0) and some text (it will be perfect if i can add the name of the branch after 1.0.1 )

Example of README.md file:

```
Version 1.0.1
Second
Version 1.0.0
First
```

Comment: man git hooks, and http://githooks.com/ will help